# Add a Visualforce Page to Case Edit Page Layout when saving

Tags: visualforce, apex

I’m trying to add the following functionality to the Case Edit Page Layout.

An user is in the Case Edit Page Layout and he selects three specific values from three picklists fields. It these three values are selected, a Visualforce page should pop up when clicking saving and before saving the record. This Visualforce page would have a Submit button to confirm that the user agrees with the information displayed in the Visualforce page. Once the Submit buttons is clicked, the Visualforce page should close and the record should be saved.

Is it possible to do this from the Case Edit Page Layout?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. Maybe you would like to include some more information regarding what have you tried already, so that people can locate potential problems with your approach.

Comment: At first glance I don't see how to do what I propose so I wonder if there is a way to get it done.